# Grafana: фильтрация аннотаций по значениям переменных дашборда

Tags: аннотации, grafana

Всем привет!

Вопрос по Grafana:
У нас используется один дашборд, где можно переключаться между разными хостами (через переменные).

Хочется отправлять Аннотации в графану, чтобы на одном дашборде были аннотации по разным хостам.
Переключился на хост1- увидел только его аннотации и т.д.
Насколько понял, у аннотаций нет labels, чтобы можно было передавать например instance=$host_name  а дальше как-то подцеплять по значению лейбла.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то решения?

Единственное решение, которое приходит в голову, это отправлять с тегами формата "host:my_host_name" а в графане как-то фильтровать по этому тегу. Но можно ли так в графане фильтровать по тегу, чтобы сравнивать со значением переменной дашборда?

Comment: О каком data source мы говорим в этом вопросе? И что такое аннотация в этом контексте?